# Posting photos on a webpage in a six columned table using PHP

Tags: php, for-loop, upload, html-table, logic

There is an upload link I'm working on, and the photos get resampled to thumbnails folder. How can I post the photos in the /thumbnails folder in a table with 6 columns?

My code below will scan the photo directory, the starting amount of files is 2 (because I var_dump the folder filepath ($files), it says 2, so I have built code to deal with that. When there are photos in this folder, the PHP script is suppose to display these photos in a 6 columned table. I'm trouble with this part and my code only displays the table row and everything under the for loop is not run. I don't know why.

The for loop (`$i % $Num_COLUMNS == $isInt && $i != 0`), I wanted to say, when `$i` (the number of photos in the folder) get to "6", `$i` divided by `$Num_COLUMNS` would equal to 1, or a whole number. Which means its time to create a new row and the pictures upload would go to after the current row. This logic is pretty bad IMO, I couldn't think of a ... better way.

```
$files = scandir("./thumbnails");
$numFiles = count($files);
$Num_COLUMNS = 6;
var_dump($files);
var_dump($numFiles);

if($numFiles < 3)
{
echo "<p>Gallery is empty </p>";
}
else 
{
echo "<p> Click on thumbnail to view larger picture! </p>";
echo "<table><tr>";
echo "the table row!";
for($i = 0; $i < $numFiles -2; $i++)
{

    if($i % $Num_COLUMNS == 0 && $i != 0)
        {
            echo "</tr><tr>";
            echo "The table row";
        }
    echo "<td>";
    echo "the table data, I CANNOT SEE ANYTHING HERE";
// below is the photo I post, and it is a link that views the picture. 
echo "<a href='ViewPicture.php?src=".urlencode($files[$i +2])."' target='_blank'><img src='".thumbnails.urlencode($files[$i + 2])."' alt='".$files[$i + 2]."' title='".$files[$i + 2]."'/></a>'";

    echo "end data table, CANNOT SEE THIS EITHER";
    echo "</td>";
}
echo "</tr> </table>";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you comparing $i % $Num_COLUMNS (an integer) with $isInt (a bool)?

You could just do:

```
<?php
//if $i is divisible by the number of columns
//and it is not 0
if($i % $Num_COLUMNS == 0 && $i != 0)
{
    echo "</tr><tr>";
    echo "The table row";
}
?>
```

Also, when you output the image, it should be:

```
<?php
echo "<a href='ViewPicture.php?src=".urlencode($files[i +2])."' target='_blank'><img src='".urlencode('./thumbnails/'.$files[$i + 2])."' alt='".$files[$i + 2]."' title='".$files[$i + 2]."'/></a>'";
?>
```

Comment: I thought of that, but when is $i % $Num_COLUMNS ever equal to 0?

Comment: That code is what I had before, same problem I have now: Will not go and echo the pictures and finish up the table mark-ups

Comment: $i % $Num_COLUMNS equals 0 when $i is a multiple of $Num_COLUMNS

Comment: Your addition to "./thumbnails/"$files[$i+2] crashes my php website with error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE

Comment: Sorry, it should have been './thumbnails/'

Comment: Sorry for late comment, but its the same error, $files is the scandir to the ./thumbnails folder already